# Finding $y$ In Calculus(Area) Problem?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, area, plane-curves

Find the number b such that the line $y=b$ divides the region bounded by the
curves $y = x^2$ and $y = 4$ into two regions with equal area.

Comment: This question has already been asked.. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482557/find-the-number-b-such-that-the-line-y-b-divides-the-region-bounded-by-the?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the value of the function between the curve and the y axis. You can ignore the second quadrant since it is symmetric

$ \int_0^k \sqrt{y}dy = \int_k^4\sqrt{y}dy$

Just solve for y and you would get the answer